# How can I query contact from lead conversion to update account field?

Tags: trigger

The situation is that I want to update a lead field that is map with contact field  over a field in the account. I have tried a trigger in the account after insert and query the child on the contact but is not working. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: please provide us what you have tried so far so that we can help you further

Comment: [code]
trigger updatefield on Account (after insert) {
Account acc = [SELECT id, name, (SELECT Contact.id, Contact.LeadSource from Account.Contacts) FROM Account ];
    if(Contact.id != null){
   if(Contact.LeadSource = 'XXXX') {
             acc.AccountSource = 'XXXX';   
        }
    }
    update acc;
}

Comment: `trigger updatefield on Account (after insert) {
    Account acc = [SELECT parentid, name, (SELECT Contact.id, Contact.LeadSource from Account.Contacts) FROM Account ]
    if(Contact.id != null){
        if(Contact.LeadSource = '') {
             acc.AccountSource = 'XXXX';    
        }}
    update acc;
}`

Comment: I'm sorry i'm pretty new on how to set the code in a comment, and it looks that i can set correctly.
I have tried to select the field from the contact and then update the field on the account. This makes sense? I have thought to do it in the opposite way, by triggering the contact but i don't know how to get the parent ID from the contact.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to update that on after insert in account object
Here is how you get the newly insert object on account

```
Trigger simpleTrigger on Account (after insert) {
    for (Account a : Trigger.new) {
        //here trigger.new contains the newly inserted record only
    }
}
```

[Here is some code that will help you code thorugh trigger](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)

and what do I think is Account is parent object to leads
after insert of account won't give us record in Leads.
confirm on this so that I can help you further.
correct me so that I can edit my answer you accordingly.

Comment: I need to trigger after insert Contact and Account, because the field i want to update in Account is mapping to a Contact field after a Lead conversion. So what i want to do is trigger after insert contact, and update parent account with the field from Contact, all this after Lead conversion.